# How to convert transform a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following values

```
Date,     value
2017/1/1, 5
2017/4/1, 6
2017/4/5, 12
2017/7/2, 15
2018/4/1, 50
2018/7/7, 11
2017/1/1, 5
```

I would like to convert this dataframe to the following format where the columns are the year/month ad the values are in the rows

```
2017/1   2017/4  2017/7  2018/1  2018/4  2018/7
 5         6     15      5       50      11
           12
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you please cross check the output you've provided with respect to your input?

Comment: I'm assuming a typo on the last date... `2018/1/1` given the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupby` and reshape to get your result:

```
v = (df.set_index('Date')['value']
       .groupby(by=lambda x: x.rsplit('/', 1)[0], axis=0)
       .apply(list))
pd.DataFrame(v.values.tolist(), index=v.index).T

   2017/1  2017/4  2017/7  2018/4  2018/7
0     5.0     6.0    15.0    50.0    11.0
1     5.0    12.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: maybe since we know these are dates, we can use something like this to handle the month:

`df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates']).map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))`

Answer (score 0):

**Sample DataFrame**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': pd.DatetimeIndex(
        ['2017-01-01', '2017-04-01', '2017-04-05',
         '2017-07-02', '2018-04-01', '2018-07-07',
         '2017-01-01'], freq=None),
     'value': [5, 6, 12, 15, 50, 11, 5]})
```

**Solution**

Create a dictionary holding the year-month as keys (string format) and values as lists of relevant values.

```
d = (df
 .assign(year_month=df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m'))
 .groupby('year_month')['value']
 .apply(list)
 .to_dict()
)

df = pd.concat([pd.Series(v, name=k) 
                for k, v in d.iteritems()], axis=1)[sorted(d)]

>>> df
   2017/01  2017/04  2017/07  2018/04  2018/07
0        5        6       15       50       11
1        5       12      NaN      NaN      NaN
```